# Joomla - Bootstrap not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0

I am changing a website into a template for Joomla 3.4.3. I am using Bootstrap 3 components and they've been working great normaly, but when it is as a Joomla template they are not working properly. Navigation toggle works only sometimes, carousel is acting weird and some animations aren't working. Also in firefox I am getting this error whenever I click somewhere:

`Empty string passed to getElementById()`

and it's refering to this code in jQuery:

```
// HANDLE: $(#id)
} else {
    elem = document.getElementById( match[2] ); // Here the error occurs
```

I've read that it can be caused by having duplicate IDs in HTML, but I have checked and didn't find any.

I would really appreciate your help, I'm really frustrated by this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the heart of joomla currently works with version 2.3.2 Bootstrap

You need to load in the template, bootstrap version you want to use.

Create a directory called "js" in the template and one for the "css"

Then add this in the template, after placing files.

```
$doc->addScript($tpath.'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
$doc->addStyleSheet($tpath.'/css/bootstrap_3.css');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the animations and carousel

Comment: but the `getElementById()` error is still occuring whenever I click, but the only thing that it seems to affect is dropdown menu. When I click on the dropdown-toggle it opens the dropdown menu after I leave the button with my mouse and it throws several of these errors. And I can't close it, only by clicking outside of the dropdown.

Comment: Ok after some reasearch I found that the dropdown button was not working because I now have two boostrap.js (one older from Joomla and the new one from my template) and one was closing it and the other one was opening it. And the error is a bug in the old Bootstrap so I'm not sure how to solve this :(

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflicts, how not to load js files it is as follows:

```
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
```

In this case, we remove the bootstrap.min.js joomla file loaded by default.

I hope I've been helpful. Sorry for my English.